# what should I do when training set contains some error data in supervised classification?

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, classification, document-classification

I am working on a project which performs text auto-classification, I have a lot of data set like as below:

### Text | CategoryName

xxxxx... |  AA

yyyyy... |  BB

zzzzz... |  AA

then, I will use the above data set to generate a classifier, once new text coming, the classifier can label new text with correct CategoryName
(text is natural language, size between 10-10000)

Now, the problem is, the original data set contains some incorrect data, (E.g. AAA should be labeled as Category AA, but it is labeled as Category BB accidentally ) because these data are classified manually. And I don't know which label is wrong and how many percentages are wrong because I can't review all data manually...

So my question is, what should I do?

- Can I find the wrong labels via some automatic way?
- How to increase precision and recall when new data coming?
- How to evaluate the impact of wrong data? (since I don't know how many percentage data is wrong)
- Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 4):

Obviously, there is no easy way to solve your problem - after all, why build a classifier if you already have a system that can detect wrong classifications.

Do you know how much the erroneous classifications affect your learning? If there are only a small percentage of them, they should not hurt the performance much. (**Edit.** Ah, apparently you don't. Anyway, I suggest you try it out - at least if you can identify a false result when you see one.)

Of course, you could always first train your system and then have it suggest classifications for the training data. This might help you identify (and correct) your faulty training data. This obviously depends on how much training data you have, and if it is sufficiently broad to allow your system to learn correct classification despite the faulty data.

Comment: Also, perhaps the presence of faulty data will actually help you to avoid overfitting.

Comment: thanks for you answer, i don't know how much the erroneous classifications affect your learning... i can't estimate it. and it contains about 5M record..it is very hard to adjust label

Comment: I got your point about active-learning and continue improve model...it really help, i can deploy my classification to production as dogfood..

Answer (score 1):

Can you review *any* of the data manually to find some mislabeled examples?  If so, you might be able to train a second classifier to identify mislabeled data, assuming there is some kind of pattern to the mislabeling.  It would be useful for you to know if mislabeling is a purely random process (it is just noise in the training data) or if mislabeling correlates with particular features of the data.

You can't evaluate the impact of mislabeled data on your specific data set if you have no estimate regarding what fraction of your training set is actually mislabeled.  You mention in a comment that you have ~5M records.  If you can correctly manually label a few hundred, you could train your classifier on that data set, then see how the classifier performs after introducing random mislabeling.  You could do this multiple times with varying percentages of mislabeled data to see the impact on your classifier.

Qualitatively, having a significant quantity of mislabeled samples will increase the impact of overfitting so it is even more important that you do not overfit your classifier to the data set.  If you have a test data set (assuming it also suffers from mislabling), then you might consider training your classifier to less-than-maximal classification accuracy on the test data set.

Answer (score 0):

People usually deal with the problem you a describing by having multiple annotators and computing their agreement (e.g. Fleiss' kappa). This is often seen as the upper bound on the performance of any classifier. If three people give you three different answers, you know the task is quite hard and your classifier stands no chance.

As a side note:
If you do not know how many of your records have been labelled incorrectly, you do not understand one of the key properties of the problem. Select 1000 records at random and spend the day reviewing their labels to get an idea. It really is time well spent. For example, I found I can easily review 500 labelled tweets per hour. Health warning: it is very tedious, but a morning spent reviewing gives me a good idea of how distracted my annotators were. If 5% of the records are incorrect, it is not such a problem. If 50 are incorrect, you should go back you your boss and tell them it can't be done.

As another side note:
Someone mentioned active learning. I think it is worth looking into options from the literature, keeping in mind labels might have to change. You said that it hard.